# RedirectFromLoginPage - The resource cannot be found error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am setting a login up in c#

```
if (TextBox1.Text == System.Convert.ToString(row["Username"]) &&
        (TextBox2.Text == System.Convert.ToString(row["Password"])))
            System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(TextBox1.Text, false);

    else
        Label1.Text = "Invalid Username/Password"; //If incorrect show this label
```

Once the user enters the correct details I get a page saying `The resource cannot be found` My question is where to I set the page which it  should be redirected to?

So far my web.config looks like this

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
 <forms>

 </forms>
```

I am connecting to a database to get the correct details, this section all works its just the redirecting of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RedirectFromLoginPage` method redirects to the page specified in the `returnUrl` query string parameter or, as a fallback, the `defaultUrl` property specified in your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

See here for more info:

RedirectFromLogin: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx

DefaultUrl: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl.aspx